# How to set a base URL for https?

Tags: php, https

I have about 7 websites on the same server/domain that reference a header file that contains CSS, JS, and other dependencies. My HTML template for those 7 sites contain this:

```
<php include "../includes/header.php" ?>
```

Unfortunately, our IT department switched something so now we need to use https in our domain name rather than http. If I remove the php include above and manually reference the updated URL, the site will work. But, rather than do this for all 7 of my websites and upate their individual pages, does anyone have any tips on a better way to reference the new https requirement? I read something about setting a base URL but not sure how to implement. Thanks.

Comment: There's no link between PHP and the network protocole. You should be able to include anything regardless if the protocole is secure.

Comment: so, setting a base url is my best solution here or should i add the baseURI syntax to an htaccess file?

Comment: PHP include use a file path, not an URL. Try `echo realpath('.');` to know where you are and check your relative path.